# ‘glSwapInterval’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: linux, windows, opengl, glx

I'm trying to port an OpenGL application from Windows to Linux.
I'm stuck at a call to `glSwapInterval` which doesn't sound windows specific, but doesn't seem to exist on Linux. What include am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Check for the [`GLX_EXT_swap_control`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/swap_control.txt) extension and use `glXSwapIntervalEXT()`.

Using something like [`GLEW`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) (via [`glxew.h`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html), see the "Platform Specific Extensions" section) makes the extension loading process easier.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `glSwapInterval (...)`, because this is fundamentally a window system operation. OpenGL splits the task of managing windows and other platform-specific operation up into separate window APIs, which include WGL (Microsoft Windows), GLX (X11), EGL (OpenGL ES and some other systems) and CGL (OS X).

Because of this split between the core API and window system API, this function will be prefixed with something other than `gl`, just as `SwapBuffers` is. On Linux chances are you are using X11, so look for `glXSwapIntervalEXT (...)`.

Comment: Yes, there is a file that does `OPENGL_PROC2(PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC, SwapInterval, wglSwapIntervalEXT);` and while `OPENGL_PROC2(PFNGLXSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC, SwapInterval, glXSwapIntervalEXT);` sounds right, it doesn't work as glXSwapIntervalEXT takes two more parameters.

Comment: @user1273684: Those two extra parameters are a pointer to your X11 display and your render context. WGL infers those things from the context that is actively bound to the calling thread, but GLX is a little bit more explicit. See the documentation for the function [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/swap_control.txt) and pay special attention to the **Usage Examples** section. You can easily get both parameters by calling two simple `glXGet` functions.